# Margin for Twitter Bootstrap 3 rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this simple code with Twitter Bootstrap 3: http://jsfiddle.net/korjavin/xUJGV/3/.

(result only: http://jsfiddle.net/korjavin/xUJGV/3/embedded/result/)

I am confused that rows with lorem-lipsum text have not any vertical margin.

I can add `margin-top` to *custom.css* but connect it to all classes like `col-sm-1(2 ..), col-xs-*, col-* ...` looks like bad solution.

What is the best solution to add vertical margin for all Bootstrap grid classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution is to respect Bootstrap rules on element nesting. A `container`, within it a `row`, within it some `col` that don't exceed `12` in total. Then, every paragraph wrapped on a `<p>`tag, and so on.

Basically your problem is about correctly using Bootstrap elements, not about CSS.

Check [an improved version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5HQgx/), also in [full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/5HQgx/embedded/result/).

Comment: So, I should look that summary of columns was < 12 ? I was think that its not important. Thank you.

Comment: And you were also nesting a `col` directly inside a `container`, I've added a `row` between them.